# How to make vim quickFix window to load a build result file?

Tags: vim

I'm on a linux c++ project development team, and the team build system dumps build result into a file named "build.result".

I am checking build problem from another colleague, and have to vi this "build.result" and check line by line by those build erros(gcc compile, link, etc), then use another terminal to change code.

This is not convenient, I wish to know if

```
1. vim can use "quickfix" window to load this "build.result"
2. so that I can traverse errors lines that has file names, and press "enter" to open them.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `vim -q build.result`

---

> ```
>                                                         -q -qf
> -q [errorfile]  QuickFix mode.  The file with the name [errorfile] is read 
>                 and the first error is displayed.  See quickfix.
>                 If [errorfile] is not given, the 'errorfile' option is used 
>                 for the file name.  See 'errorfile' for the default value.
>                 {not in Vi}
> ```

Comment: Thanks, can I do the same inside vim using any internal command?

Comment: You can use `:copen`

Comment: Sorry, I mean, inside vim, can I open this "build.result" in quickfix window? Seems ":copen" only opens and empty window if I'm already inside vim. Thanks.

Comment: It's `:cfile filename` in that case. Check `:h quickfix`. Everything will be explained.
PS: it's always possible to ignore convoluted build chains to find where the `Makefile` is hidden -- unless people call the compiler from a script (it's plain stupid, but I've already seen that)

Comment: Bingo! this is what I wanted!

Comment: Happy to help !